# felogin redirect is not working in TYPO3 9

Tags: typo3-9.x, felogin

I have upgraded my TYPO3 from 7.6.x to TYPO3 9.5.5, however i found an issue that if i try to access restricted page in url without login.
So, in normal cases it should redirect to login page and redirect working in 7 and 8 version but same thing is not working in TYPO3 9.5.5.
I have tried with following way but it gives me same following error.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same. Go to www.xyz./install.php, make a Folder ENABLE_..., reload the install.php and you are in the Backend. From this, you can start normal and after that, the Login is correct.

This was only in the last update, all others where ok.